# regex for an array output

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, tableau-desktop

Hi i have an arrow output in one of my tableau rows. How can i regex to shorten it into another calculated field.

sample 1 row has 2 items :

```
[{self=https://blah.blahblah.com/rest/api/2/component/1111, id=1111, name=abc, description=123}, {self=https://blah.blahblah.com/rest/api/2/component/123456, id=123456, name=wow, description=so cool}]
```

Output needed:

```
name=abc and description=123, name=wow and description=so cool
```

ill be using REGEXP_EXTRACT in tableau

EDIT: I can also try doing it in redshift/athena via sql before it gets into tableau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired output can be achieved with tableau calculated field and regex but it's too fragile and it's not so extensible if you data has more flexible/nested structure than in your example.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([C1],'((name)=[aA-zZ0-9 ]+)') 
+ ' and '
+ REGEXP_EXTRACT([C1],'((description)=[aA-zZ0-9 ]+)')
+ ' , ' 
+ REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1],'(\,\W+\{)([aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(name=[aA-zZ0-9 ]+)',3)
+ ' and ' 
+ REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1],'(\,\W+\{)([aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(description=[aA-zZ0-9 ]+)',3)
```

[image]

What is source of your data? If you can pack in into valid JSON you might use Redshift `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT` and `JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT` functions to prepare data before feeding tableau with it.

---

**update**

with enough `IF`s and repeats inside regex you can achieve almost anything **but at what cost**

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([C1],'((name)=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)') 
+ ' and '
+ REGEXP_EXTRACT([C1],'((description)=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)') 

+ 
IF ISNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1],'(\,\W+\{)([aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(name=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)',3))
THEN ''
ELSE ' , ' 
    + REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1],'(\,\W+\{)([aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(name=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)',3)
    + ' and ' 
    + REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1],'(\,\W+\{)([aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(description=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)',3)
END 

+
IF ISNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1], '(\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(description=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)', 2))
THEN ''
ELSE ', ' + REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1], '(\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(name=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)', 2) 
    + ' and ' + REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1], '(\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(description=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)', 2)
END 

+
IF ISNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1], '(\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(description=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)', 3))
THEN ''
ELSE ', ' + REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1], '(\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(name=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)', 3)
    + ' and ' + REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1], '(\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(description=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)', 3)
END

+
IF ISNULL(REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1], '(\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(description=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)', 3))
THEN ''
ELSE ', ' + REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1], '(\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(name=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)', 3)
    + ' and ' + REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([C1], '(\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,\}]+\,\W+\{[aA-zZ0-9 \n\/"=:.,]+)(description=[aA-zZ0-9 \-]+)', 3)
END
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, I appreciate the response. that worked when there was 2 Urls, but didnt work for 1 Url. is there any way to add a counter/if statement to capture up to 5 urls?. the source is Athena/redshift. In tableau it just looks like a string

Comment: @msulol I think updated calculation will do what you need, but it's definitely one of the most terrible thing which I ever did :) highly not recommend to use it in production. Consider some pre-processing before tableau. maybe some simple data cleaning script

Comment: thank you, this solved it for like 95% of them, is it possible to incorporate dashs and spaces? example: name=abc- Web, description=null or name=Project Tracking, description=null or name=Project-based Business, description=null